# d3 mouse over event doesn't fire correctly if set from function(d)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, pie-chart

I am working on a piechart which has a popout animation on mouseover, this is a standard animation I copied from Mike Bostocks example. It works correctly however in my case I have text in the center of the piechart which I would like to change during the mouseover event.

Code can be seen here http://codepen.io/ObiEff/pen/KpzOEz

I have tried to change the event to

```
.on("mouseover",function (d,i){

                arcTweenOut(radius,0); 
                d3.select("#costTitle")
                .text(data[i].label); 
                d3.select("#cost")
                .text("$"+data[i].value); 

            })
```

Doing this does make the text change correctly, but then the popout of the arc doesn't happen. I have tried several different ways to get them both to fire but can't figure it out.

Without adding function(d) in the mouseover binding the event function only fires once (in my console) and that is on binding of the event, however when it is bound through the function(d) it is fired everytime it is moused over, but does not perform the animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with scope in JavaScript which you can read more about [here](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/) . I've made your code work by putting the text changes in the function that the `arcTweenOut` function returns. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvxeQw

```
        function arcTweenOut(outerRadius, delay)
    {   
        // Added parameters to accept what mouseover sends
        return function(a, index) {
          // Added code here to change text/title
            d3.select("#costTitle")
            .text(data[index].label); 
            d3.select("#cost")
            .text("$"+data[index].value); 
          // END NEW CODE
            d3.select(this).transition()
              .delay(delay)
              .attrTween("d",function(d,i) {
                 var i = d3.interpolate(d.outerRadius, outerRadius);
                 return function(t) {
                    d.outerRadius = i(t);
                    return arc(d); 
                };
            });
        };
    }
```